# How to fix "NullPointerException: projectId must not be null" in Spark application on GKE?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm deploying a Spark Structured Streaming application to Google Kubernetes Engine and while accessing a bucket using `gs://` URI scheme I'm facing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: projectId must not be null
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:897)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.createBucket(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:437)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorage.createBucket(GoogleCloudStorage.java:88)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:456)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.mkdirs(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:444)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.mkdirs(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:911)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:2275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.<init>(StreamExecution.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.<init>(MicroBatchExecution.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:317)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.startQuery(DataStreamWriter.scala:466)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.startInternal(DataStreamWriter.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:301)
    at meetup.SparkStreamsApp$.delayedEndpoint$meetup$SparkStreamsApp$1(SparkStreamsApp.scala:25)
    at meetup.SparkStreamsApp$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkStreamsApp.scala:7)
```

I'm pretty sure it's related to a service account to access and create subdirectories in the bucket that I've been using while `spark-submit` the Spark app locally using `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable and `spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable=true` configuration property.

I'm deploying the Spark application as follows:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master k8s://$K8S_SERVER \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --name $POD_NAME \
  --class meetup.SparkStreamsApp \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.request.cores=400m \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores=100m \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=$SPARK_IMAGE \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=$POD_NAME \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=$K8S_NAMESPACE \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem \
  --conf spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable=true \
  --verbose \
  local:///opt/spark/jars/meetup.spark-streams-demo-0.1.0.jar $BUCKET_NAME
```

How to fix it in a proper Kubernetes / GKE-way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way in GKE documentation is to [Import credentials as a Secret](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#importing_credentials_as_a_secret) :

```sh
kubectl create secret generic spark-streaming-sa --from-file=/path/spark-streaming-serviceaccount-key.json
```

And when you submit the job add the following configurations :

```sh
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.secrets.spark-streaming-sa=<mount path>
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.secrets.spark-streaming-sa=<mount path>
--conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<mount path>/spark-streaming-sa.json
--conf spark.executorEnv.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<mount path>/spark-streaming-sa.json
--conf spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=<mount path>/spark-streaming-sa.json
```

You can refer to the examples provided on Github [GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-gcp-examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-gcp-examples/blob/master/bigquery-wordcount/README.md).

This is also described in the *Secret Management* section of spark docs [Running Spark on Kubernetes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#secret-management):

> Kubernetes [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) can be used to provide credentials for a Spark
> application to access secured services. To mount a user-specified
> secret into the driver container, users can use the configuration
> property of the form
> `spark.kubernetes.driver.secrets.[SecretName]=<mount path>`. Similarly,
> the configuration property of the form
> `spark.kubernetes.executor.secrets.[SecretName]=<mount path>` can be
> used to mount a user-specified secret into the executor containers.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your configuration I would suggest you to add the following property `fs.gs.project.id` as indicated [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/c0552aa5cfb1fc3fef7a643a1c8957529cbd2909/gcs/INSTALL.md#configure-hadoop). As it is showed up as `Required. Google Cloud Project ID with access to configured GCS buckets`.

Additional, to this I am agree with the statement from @blackbishop about the secret management.